# WPF, doesn't work OnPropertyChanged for Properties.Settings (StringCollection) in listView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I try to set content for listView from Properties.Settings (StringCollection). Contet set successful, but if i delete item, listView don't refresh. If i close and open SettingWindow, content inside listView is correct.  It's mean, something wrong in DataBinding, probably doesn't work OnPropertyChanged.

SettingWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="FilmDbApp.Views.SettingWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:p="clr-namespace:FilmDbApp.Properties"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FilmDbApp.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Setting" Height="500" Width="400" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
    <DockPanel>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Genre options">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static p:Settings.Default}, Path=Genres, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGenre}"" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <Button Command="{Binding DeleteGenreCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedGenre}" Content="Delete"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Autosave options"/>
        </TabControl>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

SettingWindow.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using FilmDbApp.ViewModels;

namespace FilmDbApp.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for SettingWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SettingWindow : Window
    {
        public SettingWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new SettingWindowViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

SettingWindowViewModel.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using FilmDbApp.Views;
using FilmDbApp.Models;
using FilmDbApp.Utils;

namespace FilmDbApp.ViewModels
{
    class SettingWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string selectedGenre;
        public string SelectedGenre
        {
            get { return selectedGenre; }

            set
            {
                selectedGenre = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedGenre");
            }
        }

        public SettingWindowViewModel()
        {

        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }

        // Delete genre
        private RelayCommand deleteGenreCommand;
        public RelayCommand DeleteGenreCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return deleteGenreCommand ??
                    (deleteGenreCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                    {
                        string genre = obj as string;
                        Properties.Settings.Default.Genres.Remove(genre);
                        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
                        OnPropertyChanged("Genres");
                    }, (obj) => Properties.Settings.Default.Genres.Count > 0 && obj != null));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you meant you are deleting a row of the list, than you need to have ObservableCollection which fires CollectionChanged Events and not PropertyChanged

Comment: you can also use refresh function from CollectionViewSource?

Comment: No, you can't update bindings like this. You are specifying different source. The easy workaround is to create getter-only property in `SettingWindowViewModel ` which will redirect to `Properties.Settings.Genres` and use it in bindings. Then you can rise notification for it in command.

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless. It only has an effect in TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: @Sinatr, I must create method inside `SettingWindowViewModel`, which will be:
1) Get items from `Properties.Settings.Genres` to `ObservableCollection`
2) Connect listView with `ObservableCollection` and do somethings
3) Convert `ObservableCollection` back to `Properties.Settings.Genres`
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of binding to some other property in some other source you can utilize the power of ViewModel, which is used to work in between of view and models.

Add following property to a ViewModel

```
class SettingWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<Genre> Genres => Properties.Settings.Default.Genres;
    ...
}
```

and bind to it

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Genres}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGenre}"... />
```

Now inside various commands you should be able to tell bindings to update

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Genres));
```